# Parsing key-values from multiple dictionaries Python

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, python-requests

I'm trying to develop a simple web app that delivers the "carpark_data" based on a user inputted value for "carpark_number" (e.g. "SK61"). I've tried researching on how to sort based on given key:values for Python dicts but I've reached a dead end.

Right now, I've got this block of code below that works for me as a static site serving out data from an API. How would I modify this code for me to serve a user who wanted to grab "carpark_data" based on whatever "carpark_number" he decided?

```
# Set the request parameters
url = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability"

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get(url)

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()
else:
    jack = response.json()
    daniel = jack['items'][0]["carpark_data"]
    print(json.dumps(daniel, indent=4)) #prints prettified jSON Data
```

Sample Output:

```
[
  {
    "carpark_info": [
        {
          "total_lots": "100",
          "lot_type": "C",
          "lots_available": "72"
        }
    ],
    "carpark_number": "SK61",
    "update_datetime": "2018-06-16T02:47:59"
  },

  {
    "carpark_info": [
      {
        "total_lots": "100",
        "lot_type": "C",
        "lots_available": "72"
      }
    ],
    "carpark_number": "SK61",
    "update_datetime": "2018-06-16T02:47:59"
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks like you want to process a list of dicts. So use a `for` loop and copy the dicts that contain the key you want. BTW, you forgot the colon after `"carpark_info"`.

Comment: when I use a for loop to iterate through these results, I get a ValueError: Too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to be able to filter the results down to the one the user is interested in? If so, this should do the trick:

```
l1 = [
      {
        "carpark_info": [
            {
              "total_lots": "100",
              "lot_type": "C",
              "lots_available": "72"
            }
        ],
        "carpark_number": "SK61",
        "update_datetime": "2018-06-16T02:47:59"
      },

      {
        "carpark_info": [
          {
            "total_lots": "100",
            "lot_type": "C",
            "lots_available": "72"
          }
        ],
        "carpark_number": "SK62",
        "update_datetime": "2018-06-16T02:47:59"
      }
    ]

wanted_carpark = 'SK62'

# use get so it doesn't fail on no number
list(filter(lambda x: x.get('carpark_number', None) == wanted_carpark, l1))
```